# SqlParameter not storing false BIT value

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

It would seem I need help getting to the bottom of what should be a simple problem.  I am updating some existing code and I have a stored procedure that has nullable paramters and updates a table.

*Example SP Parameters*

```
       ,@Paid bit = NULL
       ,@Despatched bit = NULL
```

*SP Code Example*

```
  ,Paid = ISNULL(@Paid, Paid)
  ,Despatched = ISNULL(@Despatched, Despatched)
  ,MarkedAsPaid = ISNULL(@MarkedAsPaid, MarkedAsPaid)
  ,MarkedAsDespatched = ISNULL(@MarkedAsDespatched, MarkedAsDespatched)
```

*C# Code*

```
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Despatched", 0));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Paid", 0));

   if (request.ShippedDate != null && request.ShippedDate != DateTime.MinValue.ToString())
   {
       cmd.Parameters["@Despatched"].Value = 1;
   }

   if (request.PaymentMethod == "PayPal" && request.CheckOutStatus == "NoPaymentFailure")
   {
       cmd.Parameters["@Paid"].Value = 1;
   }
```

When I run this code and the above if conditions are not met the field values remain as is (`NULL`) if they are met the field is updated to `1`. Any idea why they are not being updated to 0 when the conditions are not met?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Despatched", 0));
```

doesn't mean that the passed value is `0`, **instead it represents the `SqlDbType` enum value.** . (which is `BigInt`). Since [`0` is implicitly convertible to any enum type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304996/enum-0-value-inconsistency), you don't see an error.

Add the parameter like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Despatched",SqlDbType.Bit));
```

and then add an else statement like:

```
 if (request.ShippedDate != null && request.ShippedDate != DateTime.MinValue.ToString())
 {
     cmd.Parameters["@Despatched"].Value = 1;
 }
 else
 {
    cmd.Parameters["@Despatched"].Value = 0;
 }
```

Or you can keep your current code and add the default value like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Despatched",SqlDbType.Bit){ Value = 0 });
```

Comment: Perfect! What I find odd is that it seems to be only the `BIT` fields in the table that this is effecting.  I did try the else on the `if` but still had `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Despatched",0));`.  My next step was to change all the paramters to `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Despatched",0);` which was a lot of work given the amount of changes.  Anyway this has solved my problem :)  Thanks